# How to calculate Full joint probability distribution

Tags: probability, artificial-intelligence

This is a past exam question, I did it wrong in the exam, I'm reviewing it right now. 
The question is to compute the full joint probability of the problem below:

[image]

I draw the full joint distribution table already

[image]

I know for each entry I need to calculate something like A^B^AB^BA, but what kind of rule should I apply to get the result? by given P(A)=0.8 P(B)=0.5 P(AB) if A and B both True = 0.9 P(BA) if A and B both true = 0.9, so P(A^B^AB^BA)= 0.8*0.5*0.9*0.9 =0.324  is that right?
Also the other question : compute P(B|A, AB,-BA), I think when I finish the table I could get the answer right ?

Really need some help, Thank you.

Comment: **Note:** One way to self check your results is that the sum of all sixteen results should be $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\checkmark$ Yes.

Each entry is something like: $$\mathsf P(A\cap \neg B\cap A_B\cap \neg B_A)= \mathsf P( A)\,\mathsf P(\neg B)\,\mathsf P(A_B\mid A, \neg B)\,\mathsf P(\neg  B_A\mid  A, \neg B)$$

The rule is the *product rule* for conditional probabilities.

For any events $X,Y$ then $\mathsf P(X\cap Y)=\mathsf P(X)\mathsf P(Y\mid X)$, and **if** $X$ and $Y$ are independent then also $\mathsf P(Y\mid X)=\mathsf P(Y)$.

When you have the table: $$\mathsf P(B\mid A, A_B,-B_A) = \dfrac{\mathsf P(A\cap B\cap A_B\cap \neg B_A)}{\mathsf P(A\cap B\cap A_B\cap \neg B_A)+\mathsf P(A\cap \neg B\cap A_B\cap \neg B_A)}$$

Using the Product Rule and the Law of Total Probability.

Comment: for this equation: P(A∩¬B∩AB∩¬BA)=P(A)P(¬B)P(AB∣A,¬B)P(¬BA∣A,¬B)   I tried to decompose it like ：P(A∩¬B∩AB∩¬BA)=P(A)P(¬B)P(AB∣A,¬B,¬BA)P(¬BA∣A,¬B)  is there any difference between P(AB∣A,¬B,¬BA) and P(AB∣A,¬B)?

Comment: @roccia.  No, there isn't.  See the statement: "$A_B$ and $B_A$ are independent *given* A and B". Therefore $\mathsf P(A_B\mid A, \neg B, \neg B_A)=\mathsf P(A_B\mid A, \neg B)$