# Need help calculating full joint probability distribution

Tags: probability, artificial-intelligence

I need help calculating P(alarm) from this setup:

[image: picture 1]

This problem is similar to that in this link:

http://www.cs.tut.fi/~elomaa/teach/AI-2012-7.pdf

However, the sum of all probabilities in that link is 1.0 as seen below:

[image: picture 2]

In the (cavity, catch, toothache) in that link, P(cavity) can be calculated by adding all values of that row and gives 0.2, by the rule of marginalization:

[image: picture 3]

My problem has a total sum of 4.0, and if I add all rows in the (alarm=T) column, I will get P(alarm) = 1.100, which is greater than 1.0.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

There is a similar question posted, but there is no answer to follow.

[How to calculate Full joint probability distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/934073/how-to-calculate-full-joint-probability-distribution)

==================================================================
edit after Graham Kemp's comment

Actually, this is the problem setup. You are right.  I left out some details.  how can I solve for P(A) now?

[image: picture 4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setup is incorrect.   You appear to have the *conditional probabilities* for the events (alarm given cooking and smoke), rather than the *joint probabilities*.

---

You want. $\mathsf P(A{=}\mathsf T) ~=~ {{\mathsf P(S{=}\mathsf T,C{=}\mathsf T)~\mathsf P(A{=}\mathsf T\mid S{=}\mathsf T,C{=}\mathsf T)}+{\mathsf P(S{=}\mathsf T,C{=}\mathsf F)~\mathsf P(A{=}\mathsf T\mid S{=}\mathsf T,C{=}\mathsf F)}+{\mathsf P(S{=}\mathsf F,C{=}\mathsf T)~\mathsf P(A{=}\mathsf T\mid S{=}\mathsf F,C{=}\mathsf T)}+{\mathsf P(S{=}\mathsf F,C{=}\mathsf F)~\mathsf P(A{=}\mathsf T\mid S{=}\mathsf F,C{=}\mathsf F)}}$

You have, $\mathsf P(A{=}\mathsf T\mid S{=}\mathsf T,C{=}\mathsf T)=0.45, \mathsf P(A{=}\mathsf T\mid S{=}\mathsf T,C{=}\mathsf F)=0.15,$ et. cetera.

You are missing; $\mathsf P(S{=}\mathsf T,C{=}\mathsf T), \mathsf P(S{=}\mathsf T,C{=}\mathsf F), \mathsf P(S{=}\mathsf F, C{=}\mathsf T), \mathsf P(S{=}\mathsf F,C{=}\mathsf F)$

---

With the added information, you have $\mathsf P(S{=}\mathsf T)=0.27, \mathsf P(C{=}\mathsf T)=0.42$ and from the diagram, they are independent random variables, so $\mathsf P(S{=}\mathsf T, C{=}\mathsf T)=\mathsf P(S{=}\mathsf T)~\mathsf P(C{=}\mathsf T) = (0.27)(0.42) \\ \mathsf P(S{=}\mathsf T, C{=}\mathsf F)=\mathsf P(S{=}\mathsf T)~\mathsf P(C{=}\mathsf F) = (0.27)(0.58)\\\text{etc.} $

Then you now have enough information to calculate the join probability masses: $$\mathsf P(A{=}\mathsf T,S{=}\mathsf T,C{=}\mathsf T)=(0.27)(0.42)(0.45)=0.05103$$

And so forth.

Comment: I am using, Artificial Intelligence, a Modern Approach 3ed (Russell, Norvig), chapter 13.  The superscripts (CC), (SC), etc..... are not used.  Can you point me to a page / formula where that is used.  I do not understand this.

Comment: Sorry.  I was using $C$ as the event of Cooking, and $C^\complement$ is the complement.  I'll change it to random variables if you wish.

Comment: @CaTx Is that clearer?

Comment: I left out some details, which are now added.  How can I solve for P(A) now?

Comment: how can I computer P(A = T | S = T) from the given?

Comment: @Catx The Law of Total Probability. $$\mathsf P(A{=}\mathsf T\mid S{=}\mathsf T)~=~\mathsf P(C{=}\mathsf T)~\mathsf P(A{=}\mathsf T\mid S{=}\mathsf T,C{=}\mathsf T)+\mathsf P(C{=}\mathsf F)~\mathsf P(A{=}\mathsf T\mid S{=}\mathsf T,C{=}\mathsf F)$$

Comment: clearly, I was confused between Full Joint Distribution whose table sum is 1, and Conditional Probability.